# 2D nearest neighbour search for moving points

Tags: c++, data-structures, 2d, points, nearest-neighbor

I want do do some flocking simulation, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flocking_%28behavior%29).

For this I need to search for the nearest neighbours of each of my 2D points. However, I cannot use a static data structure like a k-d tree because the points are always moving...

What's a good (easy) datastructure/library that is able to achieve this? I'm working with C++...

Comment: You might get some ideas from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871682/approximate-nearest-neighbour-algorithm-for-moving-bodies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to try a quadtree or a spatial index? What's the problem with a k-d tree? Basically when have the edge the flock/points you can skip checking collision with edges far away. A spatial index can be a quadtree, r-tree, kd-tree or hilbert r-tree.  A better answer can be read here: [Approximate, incremental nearest-neighbour algorithm for moving bodies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871682/approximate-incremental-nearest-neighbour-algorithm-for-moving-bodies)

"That is, recursively partition the "world" into a graph with four subnodes each. The tree can then quickly check which objects are inside a particular square of the world and discard the rest. A very effective culling technique often used for improving performance of collision detection in games."

Comment: Isn't a k-d tree (or a quadtree, for that matter) static? Meaning you have to rebuild it in each step, after all the points have moved?

Comment: The idea of a quadtree is to reduce the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity. When you recursivley traverse the tree depth-first or breadth-first it becomes a simple task to fill the full tree?

Comment: I guess a quadtree would work, sort of. However, simply iterating through all neighbours seemed to be fast enough for me...

Answer (score 6):

People have [studied](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=nearest%20neighbors%20moving%20points&btnG=Search&as_sdt=0,9&as_ylo=&as_vis=0) this problem. The important keyword is kinetic, when looking for work in this ares.